# Sending notifications with action buttons from one device to all users using OneSignal

Tags: java, android, json, onesignal

I am trying to send notifications with action buttons from one device to all subscribers of my android app

here is my code

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();

    Button onSendNotification2 = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.send_notification_button2));
    onSendNotification2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            OSPermissionSubscriptionState status = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState();


                try {
                    OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'contents': {'en':'Tag substitution value for key1 = {{key1}}'}, " +
                                     "'app_id':{ '61b94305-7527-4681-a257-c3851af3ab82'},"+
                                     "'included_segments':{ ['All']},"+
                                    "'headings': {'en': 'Tag sub Title HI {{user_name}}'}, " +
                                    "'data': {'openURL': 'https://imgur.com'}," +
                                    "'buttons':[{'id': 'id1', 'text': 'Go to GreenActivity'}, {'id':'id2', 'text': 'Go to MainActivity'}]}"),
                            new OneSignal.PostNotificationResponseHandler() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , " Success :  "+ response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(JSONObject response) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , " failure :  "+ response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , " exception :  "+e , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        }
    });
```

I get Exception when I run this code , and the problem in **JSONObject code** , I don't know how to write it correctly . 
Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Please post the Exception log

Comment: @DanyPoplawec thanks , I got the solution of my problem from OneSignal Example  in Github here (https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of my problem from OneSignal Example in Github here https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK